# 8086 Assembley - call Printf in model large

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Im trying to use printf in my assembley code in model large, and i get a fixup overflow, what do i need to change in this code to make it work?

```
.MODEL LARGE
.STACK 100h
.DATA
int     DW "%d"
.CODE
.386

extrn   _printf:far
PUBLIC _stack_protection
_stack_protection PROC FAR
push    bp          
mov bp,sp           
push    es
mov     ax,10
push    ax
push    word ptr int
call    _printf
add sp,4
pop es  
pop bp          
ret 
_stack_protection ENDP
    END
```

Comment: Why do people insist on writing 16-bit assembly code?  Are you sure your printf is 16-bit?

Comment: you probably need a call FAR _printf or some flavor that distinguishes between the two call encodings.  Unless the extern did that for you, check the disassembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
int     DW "%d"
```

to this:

```
_int     DB "%d",0
```

Because `printf()` expects normal, NUL-terminated C strings, because C strings consist of bytes, not words and because `int` is likely a reserved word (at least it is in TASM).

You also need to change this:

```
push    word ptr int
...
add sp,4
```

to this:

```
push    seg _int
push    offset _int
...
add sp,6
```

Because in the large memory model all pointers are far, that is, consist of a segment and an offset.

So, this is what I end up with...

Asm file:

```
; file: larg.asm
; how to assemble: tasm.exe /ml larg.asm
.MODEL LARGE

;.STACK 100h ; unnecessary and too small anyway,
; let the C compiler take care of it

DATA segment word public 'DATA' ; make sure class='DATA' (default)
;int     DW "%d" ; 'int' is a reserved word,
; C strings must consist of bytes/chars and end with byte 0
_int    DB "%d", 0
DATA ends

extrn   _printf:far ; for some reason this must be
; outside of the code segment

CODE segment byte public 'CODE' USE16 ; make sure it's
; 16-bit code, class='CODE' (default)
assume cs:CODE
.386

PUBLIC _stack_protection
_stack_protection PROC FAR
push    bp
mov     bp,sp
push    es
mov     ax,10
push    ax
;push    word ptr int ; must be the far address of '_int'
; because in the 'large' memory model all pointers are 'far'
push    seg _int
push    offset _int
call    _printf
;add sp,4 ; must account for the far address size on stack
add     sp,6
pop     es
pop     bp
ret
_stack_protection ENDP
CODE ends

    END
```

C file:

```
// file: large.c
// how to compile: tcc.exe -mlarge large.c larg.obj

#include <stdio.h>

extern void stack_protection(void);

int main(void)
{
  stack_protection();
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I then compile the program (with Turbo C++ 1.01 and TASM 3.2):

```
tasm.exe /ml larg.asm
tcc.exe -mlarge large.c larg.obj
```

And run it:

```
c:\large.exe
10
```